# Android different widths of layouts in ViewPager

Tags: android, width, android-viewpager

I want to create some scroll view using Horizontal View Pager. Left view must has full screen width, but right only a quarter of width (it will be a vertical panel like in Dolphin browser). It's possible to do that? I changed `android:layout_width` in right layout, but it didn't work.

My code:

```
 public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.panelPager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
 }
```

main_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/panelPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final View collection, final int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.left;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.right;
        break;
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(final View arg0, final int arg1, final Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(final View arg0, final Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}
```

left.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LEFT" />

</LinearLayout>
```

right.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/light_blue" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RIGHT"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes its possible, everything is possible. Can you give some code of what you've done.

Answer (score 9):

Check Murphy's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569208/swipe-half-page-in-a-viewpager-from-compatibility-pack/10575613#10575613). You need to override PagerAdapter's `getPageWidth()` method on your PagerAdapter class, like this for example:

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int page) {
    if(page==0) {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return (float)LEFT_FRAGMENT_PIXEL_WIDTH / size.x;
    }
    else
        return super.getPageWidth(page);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source for ViewPager, this isn't something it's designed to do; it uses its own width to calculate scroll distances etc, with the clear assumption that all children will have the same width as the ViewPager itself.

For your specific case there *may* be a hacky workaround, though. You can specify a margin between adjacent pages, and this margin *can* be negative. This may give the result you want, provided the Z-ordering of the ViewPager's children is appropriate. Give it a try, and see whether it does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Adrian is exactly right. ViewPager isn't *designed* to show a portion of the next post as a preview/teaser but it **can** do it. In my `ViewPagerCursorAdapter extends PagerAdapter` class I run this:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, final int position) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    View newView = getPageView(cursor, collection);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 1) {
        ((ViewPager)collection).setPageMargin(-overlapMargin);
        if (! cursor.isLast()) { newView.setPadding(0, 0, overlapMargin, 0); }
    }
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(newView);
    return newView; //returns the object reference as the tag for identification.
}
```

You **will** run into a strange z overlapping issue. The trick is to either apply the background only to ViewPager's background or to apply it to the view *inside* the newView you just set the padding for. Looks good and works great.

Comment: I have used the above code and i am getting the childs overlapping in viewpager. Can you help me on this?