# Swipe half page in a ViewPager (from compatibility pack)

Tags: android, swipe, android-viewpager

I am using a `ViewPager` with a `PageAdapter` (from the compatibility pack v4) to swipe among a horizontal list of boxes. **The problem is that my second box from the first page is the first box in the second page** (visually and conceptually). Something like this:

[image]

The way I am doing now it works. However, this becomes kinda weird because at the middle of the swipe there is a situation that the same box appears twice (like it is shown in the image).

There is a way to swipe only "half" page?

**EDIT:**

The boxes are an abstraction. In fact each box is a `ListView` and I create different pages just changing the adapter of each `ListView`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Create one fragment per page
2. Override getPageWidth() in PageAdapter to display more than one page

Code:

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    float nbPages = 2; // You could display partial pages using a float value
    return (1 / nbPages);
}
```

Comment: Changed it, Sorry for the "delay" :)

Comment: perfect! works fine for me. going into more details default value for getPageWidth is 1f (i.e. 100% of screen area). So You can set `1/(no_of pages_per_screen_you_want)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the child width as half the page. Therefore, the swiping, which calls next child, will swipe half the page. Good Luck!

Edit: Checked your sketch again, try implementing 1st, 2nd, 3rd... as different childs. (I predict most of the solution while assuming it will react as GalleryView)

Comment: The boxes are a simplification. Actually each box is a `ListView` and each "box" have an adapter. Eitherway, how can I set the child width as half the page?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida . It turns out for me ViewPager's children always fill the ViewPager's inside bounds. Thus, i solved the problem via a little trick. Here is the source code https://github.com/MonkeyPerformingCodingAction/ViewPagerMultipleChildTrick

Comment: Already saw your code. Thanks. However, is kinda buggy :p (you can swipe only just one side, kinda tricky, maybe I didn't explain my problem right?). I want to be able to swype like I am now, but I want something like an overlap of the 2 pages when I am swiping. The way you did it you have 2 zones that you can swipe on. Feels weird.